# How do I add multiple language selection during run time to my embedded application?

Tags: c, embedded

Currently I select language at compile time, as below:

```
#define FRENCH_LANG   0
#define ZULU_LANG     0
#define ENGLISH_LANG  1


#if(FRENCH_LANG == 1)
const char PROMPT_HELLO[] = "Bonjour";
const char PROMPT_THANKS[] = "Merci";
#elif(ZULU_LANG == 1)
const char PROMPT_HELLO[] = "Sawubona";
const char PROMPT_THANKS[] = "Ngiyabonga";
#elif(ENGLISH_LANG == 1)
const char PROMPT_HELLO[] = "Hello";
const char PROMPT_THANKS[] = "Thanks";
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("%s\r\n", PROMPT_HELLO);
    printf("%s\r\n", PROMPT_THANKS);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to change my code so that all languages are compiled in and the user can select the desired language.
Is there a smart way to do this so that I do not have to duplicate or triplicate my printf's?

Comment: Why don't you use a configuration file?

Comment: I prefer to use gettext.

Comment: @mattn Even for embedded targets? It can be a bit unwieldy.

Comment: @unwind yes, case by case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a variant of [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44886724/28169)'s answer, you can go with structures and a global pointer that keeps the current language. No need for the enumeration then, and easier access by dropping one level of indirection:

```
struct strings {
  const char *hello;
  const char *thanks;
};

const struct strings strings_english = {
  .hello = "Hello",
  .thanks = "Thanks",
};
const struct strings strings_zulu = {
  .hello = "Sawubona",
  .thanks = "Ngiyabonga",
};
const struct strings_french = {
  .hello = "Bonjour",
  .thanks = "Merci",
};

static const struct strings *current_strings = NULL;

void set_language(const char *code)
{
  if(strcmp(code, "en") == 0)
    current_strings = &strings_english;
  ...
}

int main(void)
{
  set_language("en");
  printf("%s\n", current_strings->hello);
  return 0;
}
```

There are of course many things to improve here, but it can be decent. Repeating the member names (`.hello =` and so on) in the initializers makes it a bit easier to verify, and might also make life easier if/when you take the step to build tools to extract/update the text. Sometimes translation is not done by programmers, and that requires a way to get text in and out of the program.

Comment: I like this answer most and this is how I would do it (maybe with string arrays rather than a struct, but that is rather a matter of taste) as it changes the language in *one single place* - You don't have to code the language in each and every `printf`

Comment: @unwind Can i use this idea with `.hello = {0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03}`? When i end up doing a language like Cyrillic my plan was to make a lookup table and say that 0x00 = А, 0x01 = Б, 0x02 = В, 0x03 = Г.I was going to do this because i am not sure how to add unicode characters to my project.

Comment: @Richard No, you're going to have to either declare separate arrays and reference them, or just use string literals. You can use hex format in strings, i.e. `"\x1\x2\x3"`. Don't use 0, that should remain the string terminator.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it using an array of arrays of strings:

```
// Define the language indexes
#define FRENCH_LANG  0
#define ZULU_LANG    1
#define ENGLISH_LANG 2

// Number of strings translated
#define NUMBER_OF_STRINGS 2

// The translated strings
#define PROMPT_HELLO  0
#define PROMPT_THANKS 1

// Define the strings
const char *languages[3][NUMBER_OF_STRINGS] = {
    // French
    {
        "Bonjour",
        "Merci"
    },

    // Zulu
    {
        "Sawubona",
        "Ngiyabonga"
    },

    // English
    {
        "Hello",
        "Thanks"
    }
};
```

Then with a variable set to one of the language index you could do e.g.

```
int language = ENGLISH_LANG;
...
printf("%s", languages[language][PROMPT_HELLO]);
```

---

Another possible solution, very similar to the above, is to use an array of *structures*, where each member of the structure is a string for the language:

```
struct translation_strings
{
    const char *hello;
    const char *thanks;
};

// Define the language indexes
#define FRENCH_LANG  0
#define ZULU_LANG    1
#define ENGLISH_LANG 2

struct translation_strings languages[3] = {
    // French
    {
        "Bonjour",
        "Merci"
    },

    // Zulu
    {
        "Sawubona",
        "Ngiyabonga"
    },

    // English
    {
        "Hello",
        "Thanks"
    }
};

...

printf("%s", languages[language].hello);
```

---

Do note that this *will* take up a lot of space if you have lots of strings you want to have in your application. It will effectively triple the data size of your program.

If the target is a larger embedded system with possible filesystem then there might be better ways to handle translations. For example if you're targeting a Linux system then I rather suggest you look into the [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) system for handling translations (it is the de-facto standard on Linux-based systems).

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef enum 
{
    e_FRENCH  = 0,
    e_ZULU    = 1,
    e_ENGLISH = 2
} language;

const char* greetings[] = {
    "Bonjour",  /* french  */
    "Sawubona", /* zulu    */
    "Hello",    /* english */
};

void greet_in(language l)
{
    printf("%s", greetings[(int) l]);
}

int main()
{
    greet_in(e_ENGLISH); // prints "Hello"
    return 0;
}
```

You can then read a value for `language` from a configuration file or `stdin`.

Comment: And a little bit of explanation goes here as to why preprocessor definitions went away. Hiding code under "#if definition" makes it so that only defined code will be compiled, by the original post @Richard did throw away all the other languages besides English.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to change all your code, but only the initialization, you can use char pointers. The pointers have the same name as the consts had before. Of course it is possible to use smarter initialization, this is just an example.

```
lang.h
------
extern const char *PROMPT_HELLO;
extern const char *PROMPT_THANKS;

void set_lang(int lang);

lang.c
------
const char *PROMPT_HELLO;
const char *PROMPT_THANKS;

void set_lang(int lang)
{
    if (lang==FRENCH_LANG)
    {
        PROMPT_HELLO = "Bonjour";
        PROMPT_THANKS = "Merci";
    }
    else if (lang==ZULU_LANG)
    {
        PROMPT_HELLO = "Sawubona";
        PROMPT_THANKS = "Ngiyabonga";
    }
    else if (lang==ENGLISH_LANG)
    {
         PROMPT_HELLO = "Hello";
         PROMPT_THANKS = "Thanks";
     }
}
```

Finally, the program code is not changed:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    set_lang(ZULU_LANG);

    printf("%s\r\n", PROMPT_HELLO);
    printf("%s\r\n", PROMPT_THANKS);
    return 0;
}
```